# If a Corda OwnableState is owned by an AnonymousParty, who stores it?

Tags: corda

In Corda, an `OwnableState` must specify an `AbstractParty` as an owner. There are two types of `AbstractParty`:

- `Party`, with a well-known identity
- `AnonymousParty`, identified solely by public key

If I create a `CompositeKey` to own the `OwnableState`, who then will store it in their vault as part of `FinalityFlow`?

Comment: These issues would not arise with state types other than `OwnableState`, since they would be stored on the basis of the state's participants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment nobody will unless lower level APIs are used.

The vault needs more work to fully understand multi-sig states, e.g. with cash, we need a way to select coins that we're participants of.

It's quite an advanced feature because composite keys have so many use cases. This is typical in the blockchain space, Bitcoin supported CHECKMULTISIG outputs in the protocol long before wallets that knew how to use them existed. And when wallets did start to appear, they had different code and features for different use cases. E.g. using multisig/composite keys for more secure wallets is different to using them to do dispute mediation protocols.
 At least with flows we have a straightforward way to implement support - we can make flows that understand composite keys and either have the certs linking the components to real parties, or know who they are some other way, and then go gather the signatures automatically.